How can I change the position of 3D glb model in my website pages?
I work with Three.js, and I've added a 3D .gbl model to my website page. However, it always appears in the center of the page, and I want to change its position to wherever I choose (e.g., top-left of the page). Despite trying several solutions, none of them have worked for me.
My code:
  import React, { Suspense, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
  import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
  import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF, Center } from "@react-three/drei";
  import CanvasLoader from "../Loader";
  import * as THREE from "three";

  const Computers = (position) => {
  const { scene, animations } = useGLTF("./public/android/android_bug.glb");
  const ref = useRef();
  const mixer = useRef();
  const [bodyColor, setBodyColor] = useState("#FF7043");
  const eyeColor = "#000000";

  useEffect(() => {
    if (animations.length) {
      mixer.current = new THREE.AnimationMixer(scene);
      animations.forEach((clip) => {
        mixer.current.clipAction(clip).play();
      });
    }
    if (scene) {
      scene.traverse((child) => {
        if (child.isMesh) {
          if (
            child.name.toLowerCase().includes("eye") ||
            child.material.name === "EyeMaterial"
          ) {
            child.material.color.set(eyeColor);
          } else {
            child.material.color.set(bodyColor);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }, [scene, animations, bodyColor, eyeColor]);

  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    if (mixer.current) mixer.current.update(delta);
  });

  return (
    <primitive
      ref={ref}
      object={scene}
      scale={1.5}
      position={[0, 0, 0]}
      rotation={[0, 0, 0]}
    />
  );
};

const ComputerCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <div >
      <Canvas
        frameLoop="demand"
        shadows
        camera={{ position: [0, 5, 5], fov: 25 }}
        gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
      >
        <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
          <OrbitControls
            enableZoom={false}
            maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
            minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          />
          <ambientLight intensity={1.5} />
          <directionalLight position={[-1, 2, 8]} intensity={1.5} />
          <Computers />
        </Suspense>
        <Preload all />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );


export default ComputerCanvas;

nb: when I change the position values of the primitive balise in computers return, the 3D model's rotation changes instead of its actual position.
